# How to properly use asp.net web forms with jquery & jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am currently using jquery with asp.net web forms,
The images fetch from database & show in listview, then when user click on particular image i want to get its primary key id which is in data base, but when i click on any image the onClick & onSelectedIndex event is not raised, i don't know whats the problem with this. I am using jquery to scroll images.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Please edit to make it clear, or the question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You add an attribute to image tag, and then use jquery to process this value of this attribute

Comment: i have listview dude! images are showing correctly, events are not raising actually,